# Get single record from has_many using eager-loading in include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and stuck between eager-loading from last 2 days.
I have two models `Car` and `Images` with `Car has_many :images` association. and I have made an api which returns json array of cars with their images. I want single image instead all images from association.
I'm using like:

```
Car.where(:company=>"BMW").as_json(:include=> {:images})
```

This will return all the cars with their all images.
I want all cars with their single image instead of all images array.

Comment: Add another association in `Car` model: `has_one :image` then you can do: `Car.where(:company=>"BMW").as_json(:include=> {:image})`

Comment: @Nitisha - which image do you want: the first?

Comment: Maybe add a flag to the "images" that defines a primary image and constrain this to one through validation.

Comment: Actually, I need last updated image if possible otherwise any of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `has_one :image, -> { order(updated_at: :desc) }` to `Car` model. This will define a `default_scope` to the association.

Then you could get all cars with only one last updated image per car:

`Car.where(company: 'BMW').as_json(include: [:image])`

Comment: I dont think `default_scope` in general is a good idea. [First](http://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/rails/best-practices/why-using-default-scope-is-a-bad-idea.html) and [second](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/) link to explain why

Comment: @MartinZinovsky you mixed up this. Your links talk about `default_scope` for entire model. My approach to add it only to association.

Comment: is it good to define two different relationships for image like has_many :images and has_many :image ?

Comment: @Nitisha it's up to your needs. In that case it would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend what you need.

1. If You need first, please write: `Car.where(company: "BMW").first`
2. If you need last, please write: `Car.where(company: "BMW").last`

Is it enough for you?

If you have has_many association you have to choose what record you need (maybe add some flag). Without that you will have collection from all association object.

One more is better to use `where(company: "BMW")` than `where(:company => "BMW")`

Comment: did you read my problem?I think not as per your answer, this is not a good trick to writing anything to increase upvotes. Meaningful answers will automatically upvote by users.